# Не удается запустить Django в PyCharm с помощью ./manage.py runsevrer

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, poetry

Я создал проект в Pycharm, выбрав в качестве интерпретатора новое Poetry-окружение. Я делал все в соответствии с гайдом, установил django, создал проект, перешел в /project_name, но почему-то не смог запустить django командой `./manage.py runserver`, ничего вообще не происходит, как видно на скриншоте, команда завершается и я могу вводить новую, но эффекта никакого нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогла мне команда `python manage.py runserver`, но я не понимаю, почему с помощью классической команды, указанной во всех источниках, у меня не получается запустить проект.

Comment: "но я не понимаю, почему с помощью классической команды, указанной во всех источниках, у меня не получается запустить проект." - командная строка `./manage.py runserver` работает под Linux при настроенном режиме запуска файла (`chmod +x manage.py`) при условии, что в начале файла есть shebang строка (что-то типа `#!/bin/env python3`). Под Windows надежно только через python.